# How do I match an exact numerical string in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have multiple ID's in a single field like this

```
field_name
+----------+
12345|34456|43564
```

Now what I wanted is to get the row if it matches even a single number perfectly so I searched a little and I found this and used it in my query but it failed

```
SELECT field_name FROM tbl_name WHERE field_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]34456[[:>:]]';
```

So I used this a back-slash and it worked,

```
SELECT field_name FROM tbl_name WHERE field_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]34456\[[:>:]]';
```

so is it perfect or I am going wrong somewhere? I need an exact match, I don't want that that am hunting for 34456 and if 34457 is there and it takes that, I want `EXACT` match, and I can't use `WHERE` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, no solution is going to be "perfect" if you store ids like that :)

MySQL has a function called [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) that can be useful for this type of task, but it assumes your list is comma-delimited. So you'll need to replace the pipes with commas in order to use that function.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT field_name 
FROM tbl_name 
WHERE find_in_set('34456',replace(field_name,'|',',')) > 0;
```

Comment: than I can get the exact 1? and please can you explain me the regex am using, but If this works than am not going for regex

Comment: Yes, this will return exact matches only, and should be more readable for you if you are not comfortable with REGEXP. Try it out!